# Access Calendar through Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

For Coded UI, I want to access the Calendar through Hand Coding and Note that Textbox which displays the selected date is not editable manually so Setproperty does not work.
Please Help.

Comment: Please add some code snippet.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add your code and additional explanations. Answers are for answers, they are not for adding extra details.

Comment: When we click on read only textbox, it opens calendar. I have to write the code for selecting date from date through coded ui.

Comment: When the Textbox is editable, this works:


 UITestControl TextboxDOJ = new UITestControl(browser);
            TextboxDOJ.TechnologyName = "web";
            TextboxDOJ.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Edit");
            TextboxDOJ.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "ctl00_Main_CreateEmployee1_txtDOJ");
            TextboxDOJ.SetProperty("Text", "18/01/2016");

Comment: I also tried with Recorded method but its still not working. Please let me know how to write same as above way for non editable textbox.